# Pyramid of stars using while loops python nested while loops

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I have been having trouble with something I am working on for the past two days trying to make a pyramid of stars using while loops from user input

an example of the final result would look like this:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```

but I am not even clearly sure how this is supposed to work. As I have tried for the past two nights to figure this problem out.

This is all I have so far:

```
userInput = int(input("Please enter the amount of rows: "))
count = 1
spacing = 0
actualStars = "*"
numberStars = 0
rows = 0
while(userInput <= rows):
    rows += count
    print()
    while(spacing <= userInput):
        spacing += count
        print(" ")
        while(numberStars <= 0):
            print(actualStars)
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? And does it specifically say that you need to use while loops?

Comment: yes it specifies 3 while loops

Comment: I would first take a look at your conditions.

Comment: Forget the spaces for a second. Are you able to just print 1 star, then 2 stars, etc..?

Comment: Hint: in python, you can write `a = '*' * 10` which does the same as `a='**********'`.  You can also concatenate strings `b='X' * 3 + 'O' * 4` is equivalent to  `b='XXXOOOO'`.  You therefore need only **one** loop.  So each line prints a sequence of spaces followed by another sequence of starts.  Just figure how many of each you have to print on each line.  (Unless your assignment specifically asks for multiple loops, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework, rather than give you a code answer, I'll give you an outline of how this should work.  Given the constraint of three loops, here is what seems to be expected:

1. The first, outer loop should iterate over the rows.  The first pass generates the first row, the second pass generates the second row, etc.
2. The second loop is nested inside the first loop.  It generates the leading spaces for the current row.
3. The third loop is also nested inside the first loop, but *not* the second.  It is executed after the second loop, and should follow it in your code.  It generates the stars for the current row.

Each of these loops is very simple and you should have no trouble with them.  The only tricky part is getting `print` to print a string without following it with a newline character (which ends the current line).  If you're using Python 3, you can do this with `print("abc", end="")`  This will print the string `abc` but will not end the line.  After the third loop, you *will* need to end the line, which you can do with `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

A few immediate problems I see with your code

- `print(' ')` without doing `print(' ', end='')` will print a newline, but you don't want that until you've printed all the spaces and stars
- `while(userInput <= rows)` unless you enter a nonpositive number, this won't run since `rows = 0`
- For every time you print the spaces, you are printing stars. That isn't correct because you need to print the spaces and **then** the stars

Here is the correct code. Also note that a pyramid has 1 star, 3 stars, 5 stars, etc. for row 1, row 2, row 3. This can be generalized as `2*row-1` stars

```
userInput = int(input("Please enter the amount of rows: "))

row = 0
while(row < userInput):
    row += 1
    spaces = userInput - row

    spaces_counter = 0
    while(spaces_counter < spaces):
        print(" ", end='')
        spaces_counter += 1

    num_stars = 2*row-1
    while(num_stars > 0):
        print("*", end='')
        num_stars -= 1

    print()
```

Example

```
Please enter the amount of rows:  5
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Comment: @TomKarzes OP obviously had an attempt, The question was not "give me code". I also explained what OP was doing wrong, so this isn't a "code only" answer

Answer (score 0):

So, let's approach this arithmetically. The first row needs one star, the second row needs two stars, and the third row needs three stars, etc.

In other words the number of stars is equal to the current row index (assuming you start your index at 1). Python's string format method allows you to specify centered strings and you can multiply the stars by the row index, since strings in Python implement the multiplication protocol **mul**:

```
i = 0
rows = 8
while i <= rows:
  print("{:^8}".format("*"*i))
  i += 1
```

This will output the following:

```
   *    
   **   
  ***   
  ****  
 *****  
 ****** 
******* 
********
```

As you can see, it's a little lopsided, but we're on the right track. It's lopsided because the number of 'columns' is even, and when there's an odd number of stars, they can't be centered. The exact opposite would occur if we had an odd number of columns.

So, how do we center these? There are a few ways to approach it, but I would just make every row of stars odd by printing a space between every star. At this point they are perfectly centered.

All you need to do is add another two loops that:

1) Replicate the format() template's white space padding

2) Create the 'true' centered string by putting a space between stars

This could be done with three while loops, but I don't see how that's pythonic. But I didn't write the assignment :)

hth

Comment: The wonky pyramid of stars :D.

Comment: The number of stars should increase by 2 on each row, not 1

Answer (score 0):

```
userInput=int(input("Please enter the amount of rows:"))
row=""
count =1
spacing =0
star=0
u=0
while(count <=userInput):
    spacing =spacing +count 
    while(spacing<userInput):
        row+=" "
        spacing +=1
    star=count +u
    while(star>0):
        row+="*"
        star-=1
    count +=1
    spacing=0
    u+=1
    print(row)
    row*=-1
```

Comment: The way to work the pyramid Najob using String.The excuse is if there is a failure to explain the code

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21999038)